# iPhone - UITableViewCell white after selected

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

How is it possible that my UITableViewCell (Static cells) after i selected it become white again? When i tap on it , it becomes grey and stays grey! It should be grey for a short time if i tap on it.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Normally when you tap on a UITableViewCell - the background color of the cell turns grey for a short time. But my problem is in my application, when i tap on the cell, the background color of the cell stays grey. And I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: can you mention your problem clearly.

Comment: @MuthuRam , i tried to explain it a little bit better in my edit

Comment: what are control and gesture you have used in tableview cell

Comment: i just use the DidSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to deselect the cell in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // do stuff

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 2.0+

This tableview delegate method is called each time you tap a cell in the tableview, it will provide you the 'indexPath' the user tapped (which is essentially which cell the user tapped). In the body of this method simply deselect the tapped cell which will turn it back to its non-selected status.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{
     tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Set following code to your tableview

```
tableView.allowsSelection = false
```

2) Also check the tableview cell is return correctly. Some times people accidentally return as below

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

So here double check, you should return the created cell instead of tableviewCell instance